# PHP Associative Arrays - Single vs Double Quotes

Tags: php

Is there any difference between using single and double `quotation` marks for `Associative` `arrays` names in `PHP` ?

e.g.:

$age = array("Peter"=>"35", "Ben"=>"37", "Joe"=>"43");

$age = array('Peter'=>'35', 'Ben'=>'37', 'Joe'=>'43');

Comment: Both work, but maybe, one of them is faster or will be following some rule I don't know

Comment: In terms of speed: run a few hundred thousand random strings and measure the time. That may depend on the PHP version as well, see my answer for short explanation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Practically no.
There is a slight difference, though. If you use double quotes, the string will be computed; embedded variables will be expanded.
Single quotes on the other side are literals. They are handled as-is.

I *could* imagine that the double quotes produce a **slight** overhead due to computing, but I doubt it's significant.

I personally use single quotes for programmatic stuff and double quotes for user-presented text, unless required otherwise.
That's a neat little rule making life easier ;-)

Comment: Actually single quotes is faster but not by any amount that matters. The double quotes is faster thing is a myth.

Comment: Never actually heard of that myth... Yeah, that's what I'd assume from a native developers perspective and as I said, I doubt as well, that the difference is somewhat significant. Would be fun to test, though...

Comment: I always heard that single quotes were faster cause PHP don't parse the content

Comment: John and I would agree. Faster, but not faster enough to be reasonably faster. You're welcome as always

Comment: I like the "rule" to use single quotes for programmatic stuff and double quotes for user-presented text. This also implies that generating HTML-code uses double-quotes, which is logical.

Answer (score 0):

No, apart from the general PHP rules regarding the quotes. See also http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 0):

No.

Single vs. double `quotes` in this context only matters if the thing between the `quotes` is a `variable`.

For example, if `$Test = 43,`

```
$Var["$Test"] = $Var["43"] but $Var['$Test'] = $Var['$Test']
```